# How should I get the value contained in a particular field of a Drupal 7 custom node?

Tags: php, api, drupal, field, drupal-7

What is the "proper" way to get the value stored in a particular field within a custom Drupal node? I've created a custom module, with a custom node, with a custom *URL* field. The following works:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE title = :title AND type = :type", array(
  ':title' => $title,
  ':type' => 'custom',
))->fetchField();
$node = node_load($result);
$url = $node->url['und']['0']['value'];
```

...but is there a better way, maybe using the new Field API functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`node_load()` then accessing the field as a property is the proper way, although I'd do it slightly differently to avoid hard-coding the locale:

```
$lang = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node = node_load($nid);
$url = $node->url[$lang][0]['value'];
```

The method you're using to get the nid is a particularly kludgy way to derive it; I'd focus on refactoring that and use [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) and [entity_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_load/7) instead:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', $node_type)
  ->propertyCondition('title', $title)
  ->execute();

// $result['node'] contains a list of nids where the title matches
if (!empty($result['node']) {
  // You could use node_load_multiple() instead of entity_load() for nodes
  $nodes = entity_load('node', $result['node']);
}
```

You'd want to do this especially since title is not a unique property and if the field appears on entities other than nodes. In that case you'd remove the `entityCondition()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Do you know of a better way to get the nid, given only the title of a node to go on?

Comment: @Matt I'd use `EntityFieldQuery` and the entity API, especially considering fields can appear on things other than nodes. I've updated my answer with a possible way to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why EntityFieldQuery is being discussed, but ok. :) You're actually going to want to use the [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function.

```
if ($nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => 'custom', 'title' => $title)) {
  $node = reset($nodes);
  if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'url')) {
    $url = $items[0]['value'];
    // Do whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: `EntityFieldQuery` is being discussed because the conditions parameter for `node_load_multiple()` you're using in your code [is deprecated](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) in favor of `EntityFieldQuery`. And [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7) is the long way around doing the exact same thing as accessing the field as a property on the node.

Comment: It's true that the parameter has been deprecated, but [`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7) is still using it. It will be probably not used on Drupal 8, but I would think that is safe to use it with Drupal 7.

Answer (score -1):

propertyCondition('field_order_no', 'value', 'search key', '=')

field_order_no is the slug of custom field & Search Key is the value to be matched with